# MVC 4 with DataTables (nuget mvc.jquery.datatables)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I downloaded the nuget package mvc.jquery.datatables from https://github.com/mcintyre321/mvc.jquery.datatables it was designed to run with MVC 3.

I found that a few changes were required to work with MVC 4 as posted on 
http://www.distribucon.com/blog/jQueryDataTablesInASPNETMVC.aspx

I cannot see why I get the message "Loading data from server" and the method in my controller is never called.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to register the JQuery bundlefirst.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```